# C# Programmatic created button - enable programmatically created textbox

Tags: c#, database, winforms

Hoping you can help - I have programmatically created button & richtextbox.

```
// Button to Edit
Button butEditToDo = new Button();
butEditToDo.Location = new Point(285, 10);
butEditToDo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
butEditToDo.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
butEditToDo.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
butEditToDo.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
butEditToDo.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(244, 244, 244);
butEditToDo.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
butEditToDo.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Edit_25));
pnlPendingNote.Controls.Add(butEditToDo);

// Pending Nane + Tag
RichTextBox rxtNotes = new RichTextBox();
rxtNotes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(317, 68);
rxtNotes.Location = new Point(3, 37);
rxtNotes.Text = (read["notNote"].ToString());
rxtNotes.ReadOnly = true;
rxtNotes.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
rxtNotes.DetectUrls = true;
rxtNotes.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(244, 244, 244);
pnlPendingNote.Controls.Add(rxtNotes);
```

So when ever I click on ButEditToDo_Click - I can get the right button clicked.

So when I click on this button I would like to enable the RichTextbox - and when I click the button again - I would like to update the database.

Button Click:

```
private void ButEditToDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    for (int i = 1; i < pendingcounter; i++)
    {
        if (btn.Name == ("PenNote" + i))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help please with enabling the button, I'm all good with the database.

Thank you.

**Edit One**

@Ed - thank you. 
Please See Image. [image]

What I would like to achieve - When i click on the tools icon - the RichTextBox will be enabled. 
So if I click on the tools on first panel - then the R_TextBox will be enabled for me to edit the text. 
Then the Icon will change and I will be able to click on it again to save to the database.

Hope that makes more sense for you Ed.

Comment: My answer showed you how to do what you need to. If there are more controls involved that you didn't mention initially, it can be generalized. The same principles apply. I didn't intend to provide a completely, tested, debugged implementation, and I'd have no interest in doing so even if your explanation made any sense to me. Unfortunately, you seem to want somebody to write the code for you. Coding that doesn't interest me costs US$200/hour (special inflated holiday rate); let me know if you can afford that. Minimum three hours.

Comment: I didn't mean for your to write my code - I have successfully implemented the solution with your help. -  I just added little information - as per your last sentence - in the event you thought of something else. 
I'm learning C#, all I need is help with understanding - I'm more comfortable with html, css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the button an event handler that does stuff. Use a lambda so you can reference the local reference to the RichTextBox.

```
    Button butEditToDo = new Button();
    //  ...snip...
    RichTextBox rxtNotes = new RichTextBox();
    //  ...snip...

    butEditToDo.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        CycleNoteState(rxtNotes);
    };
```

And here's the guts of the event handler. You could put this all in the event handler, but the code's more readable this way. `CycleNoteState` isn't a very good name, but I'm not clear about the semantics of your program.

I may have misunderstood the logic for what the button does on successive clicks. If it's more complicated than this, you can introduce a state enum or something. Let me know and we'll get it figured out.

```
private void CycleNoteState(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    if (!rtb.Enabled)
    {
        rtb.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //  Do save stuff here
    }
}
```